# How to get (automatic) offsets in logscale plots?

Tags: gnuplot

The option `set offsets` has no effect on log plots.

For instance, both figures below have been generated with `set offsets 0,2,0,0`:

[image][image]

In order to obtain the same effect I'm currently setting fixed ranges instead of using autoscale, which is non-optimal, as the script is intended for generating plots from data in batch.

Since Gnuplot 5.2, [we have](http://www.gnuplot.info/ReleaseNotes_5_2_7.html) '*"set log" re-implemented as special case of "set nonlinear"*', and set nonlinear [makes use](http://www.bersch.net/gnuplot-doc/set-show.html#commands-set-nonlinear) of two axis, as it '*is similar to the [set link](http://www.bersch.net/gnuplot-doc/set-show.html#set-link) command except that only one of the two linked axes is visible*', and, since the documentation also [makes clear](http://www.bersch.net/gnuplot-doc/set-show.html#commands-set-offsets) that '*The offsets only affect the x1 and y1 axes*', it appears that instead of a bug this is expected behavior.

**Question**: Is there a simple way of obtaining a similar autoscaled offset for log plots?

I suppose one can make a dummy plot and use the data ranges for setting the axis ranges in the outputted plot, but is there a better way?

For the sake of completeness, minimum codes for generating the figures above are:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 250,250
set output "1.png"
set offsets 0,2,0,0
plot [0.1:1] 1/x
```

and

```
set terminal pngcairo size 250,250
set output "2.png"
set logscale
set offsets 0,2,0,0
plot [0.1:1] 1/x
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned in your question, you can create a dummy plot and
add your offset to the ranges.

The point is that you can get the `GPVAL_...` variables only *after* plotting.
So, currently I don't see another way to create a dummy plot unless this offset for logarithmic axes will be implemented in gnuplot itself.

The following example is an attempt to make this replot maybe a bit easier to handle using `macros` and `evaluate()`, see `help macros` and `help evaluate`.
Perhaps it is a bit of a simplification if you batch process many plots. Maybe somebody will find a way to shorten this a bit.

Of course, you can also set `myRange = [*:*]` for autorange and `myOffsets` will be added to the autorange limits.

**Code:**

```
### offsets for logarithmic scale
reset session
set term pngcairo size 300,300

SetMyOffsets(n) = sprintf("[%g:%g][%g:%g]", \
                    GPVAL_X_MIN-word(myOffsets,1), \
                    GPVAL_X_MAX+word(myOffsets,2), \
                    GPVAL_Y_MIN-word(myOffsets,4), \
                    GPVAL_Y_MAX+word(myOffsets,3))

GenerateOutput = 'set output myOutput; \
                  eval(myPlot); \
                  set output; \
                  set output myOutput; \
                  myRange=SetMyOffsets(0); \
                  eval(myPlot); \
                  set output'

# first plot with linear x-axis
myRange = '[0.1:1]'
myPlot  = 'plot @myRange 1/x'
myOffsets = '0 2 0 0'           # left right top bottom
myOutput = "Linear.png"
@GenerateOutput

# second plot with log x-axis
set logscale
myRange   = '[0.1:1]'
myPlot    = 'plot @myRange 1/x'
myOffsets = '0 2 0 0'           # l r t b
myOutput = "Logarithmic.png"
@GenerateOutput

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image][image]